# Add modified outline dictionary in pdf using Pypdf

Tags: python, pypdf, bookmarks

I had to increment pagenumber of all bookmarks in a pdf when combining multiple pdfs using pypdf

```py
from pypdf import PdfReader

pdf_reader = PdfReader("example.pdf")

outlines = pdf_reader.outline
print("old outline", outlines)
increment_value = int(total_pages)
print("increased by", increment_value)
for outline in outlines:
    page_key = NameObject("/Page")
    if page_key in outline:
        current_page_number = outline[page_key]
        new_page_number = NumberObject(current_page_number + increment_value)
        outline.update({page_key: new_page_number})

print("Modified outlines:", outlines)

pdf_writer.append(input_file, import_outline=False)
for outline in outlines:
    print("show single outline", outline)

    # add the modifiedoutline
    pdf_writer.add_outline(outline, outline[page_key])
```

Trying to add the modified outline, not working throwing error,
TypeError: PdfWriter.add_outline() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

output [image]

How to to add the modified outlines to the pdf

Comment: Copy the full Traceback. Read it. Very likely, you will see the issue then.

Answer (score 0):

solved using .add_outline_item,tested and worked

```
for outline in outlines:
    page_key = NameObject('/Page')

    try:
        if page_key in outline:
            current_page_number = outline[page_key]
            print("this is current_page_number", current_page_number)

            new_page_number = NumberObject(current_page_number + increment_value)
            outline.update({page_key: new_page_number})
    except:
        print("error")

print("Modified outlines:", outlines)

pdf_writer.append(input_file, import_outline=False)
for x in outlines:
    print(x)
    try:
        pdf_writer.add_outline_item(x['/Title'], x['/Page'])
    except Exception as e:
        errormsg = "error>" + pdf_file
        print("error" + pdf_file)
```